# get current node value through xpath

Tags: java, xpath

```
<E  st="SS"  >
        <id>789</id>
        <name>Study  Table 1200 C2</name>
        <vlid>1</vlid>
        <E  st="SS"  >
            <id>567</id>
            <name>Study  Table1</name>
            <vlid>94611431277729312</vlid>
        </E>
        <E  st="SS"  >
            <id>345</id>
            <name>Study -SOFT1</name>
            <vlid>94611431277729311</vlid>
        </E>
        <E  st="SS"  >
            <id>123</id>
            <name>Study  Table 02</name>
             <vlid>94611431277729309</vlid>
        </E>
    </E>
```

in this i am trying to get the node Value of id where vlid=3.
the xpath i have written is (`//E[vlid=94611431277729312]/id`). the result is `<id>567</id>,<id>345</id><id>123</id>`

rather i want only one id i.e `<id>567</id>`.
please help me out why i am unable to get the excepted output.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work if you will match the value as string

```
//E[vlid="94611431277729312"]/id
```

Comment: You're welcome. I can't give link as to why matching with `int` will not give the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//E[vlid=3]/id[2]
```

Like Colin said, try to accept answers that solve your problem.

Comment: yes this is working. but i have a huge xml. i have to get the value of the node with its vlid,as its unique to everyone node presents in that xml. any other way is there for this problem?

Comment: and now onward i will accept answers that solve my problem also. Thanks